# How to deal with Break statement that is causing Issue for Pester on Should -Invoke Command

Tags: powershell, pester

I noticed something peculiar when using `Should -Invoke` on a Mock command. When running without a `Break` statement in the Code Block, `Should -Invoke` works perfectly fine; but when running with a `Break` statement, `Should -Invoke` will always validate as TRUE, that is, Pester will pass all tests.

I do not want to remove `Break` statement from my original `.ps1` script as I need this. Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way that I can Mock `Break` statement using pester or if there are any workaround for this, so that i can continue to validate all Mock commands without removing `Break` statement from my source code.

Below is the code that I used to show the behavior of `Break` statement given in the `else` code block when running with Pester. Notice that `Context VALIDATE ELSE BLOCK` passes all tests.

```
BeforeAll {
    function Something-Function {
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$SamplePath
        )
    
        Write-Host "Hello from Function"
    
        if (Test-Path -Path $SamplePath -PathType Leaf) {
            Write-Host "Hello from If"

            "Hello Earth!" | Out-File $SamplePath -Encoding utf8 -Append
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Hello from Else"
    
            "Hello World!!" | Out-File $SamplePath -Encoding utf8 -Append

            Break
        }
    }
}

Describe "Something-Function" {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock Write-Host {}

        $TestPath = "TestDrive:\"
        $FileName = "fake.txt"
    }

    Context "VALIDATE IF BLOCK" {
        BeforeAll {
            Mock Test-Path -MockWith {return $true}

            # New-Item -ItemType File -Path $($TestPath + $FileName) -Force
            "Hello World!!" | Out-File $($TestPath + $FileName) -Encoding utf8 -Append
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2
        }

    }

    Context "VALIDATE ELSE BLOCK" {
        BeforeAll {
            Mock Test-Path -MockWith {return $false}
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 3" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 3
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Out-File -Exactly -Times 50" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 50
        }

        It "Should -Invoke Import-Csv -Exactly -Times 100" {
            Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
            Should -Invoke Import-Csv -Exactly -Times 100
        }
    }
}

# PS C:\user\repo> Invoke-Pester -Output Detailed .\TEST\Issue.tests.ps1
# Pester v5.3.3

# Starting discovery in 1 files.
# Discovery found 7 tests in 199ms.
# Running tests.

# Running tests from 'C:\user\repo\TEST\Issue.tests.ps1'
# Describing Something-Function
#  Context VALIDATE IF BLOCK
#    [-] Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1 96ms (93ms|3ms)
#     Expected Write-Host to be called 1 times exactly but was called 2 times
#     at Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1, C:\user\repo\TEST\Issue.tests.ps1:42
#     at <ScriptBlock>, C:\user\repo\TEST\Issue.tests.ps1:42
#    [+] Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2 34ms (34ms|0ms)
#  Context VALIDATE ELSE BLOCK
#    [+] Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1 69ms (66ms|3ms)
#    [+] Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 2 35ms (34ms|0ms)
#    [+] Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 3 33ms (33ms|0ms)
#    [+] Should -Invoke Out-File -Exactly -Times 50 35ms (34ms|0ms)
#    [+] Should -Invoke Import-Csv -Exactly -Times 100 35ms (34ms|1ms)
# Tests completed in 739ms
# Tests Passed: 6, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

I have try mocking `Break` statement `Mock Break {}` but failed and generate the below error.

```
[-] Context Something-Function.VALIDATE ELSE BLOCK failed
   CommandNotFoundException: Could not find Command Break
```

Comment: Re "I do not want to remove `Break` statement from my original `.ps1` script" - you _should_, however, because a `break` or `continue` statement _outside a loop-like statement_ amounts to _broken code_ - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow the link in @mklement0's comment above you'll see this:

> #### [Do not use break outside of a loop, switch, or trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.4#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap)
>
> When break is used outside of a construct that directly supports it (loops, switch, trap), PowerShell looks up the call stack for an enclosing construct. If it can't find an enclosing construct, the current runspace is quietly terminated.
>
> This means that functions and scripts that inadvertently use a break outside of an enclosing construct that supports it can inadvertently terminate their callers.
>
> Using break inside a pipeline break, such as a ForEach-Object script block, not only exits the pipeline, it potentially terminates the entire runspace.

The following **bad** code demonstrates this in action:

```
#
# BAD CODE FOLLOWS - DON'T DO THIS !!!
#

function Test-Outer
{
    $x = 1
    write-host "entering outer"
    switch( $x )
    {
        1 {
            write-host "outer before"
            Test-Inner $x
            write-host "outer after"
        }
    }
    write-host "leaving outer"
}

function Test-Inner
{
    param( $y )
    if( $y -eq 1 )
    {
        write-host "inner before"
        # DON'T DO THIS OUTSIDE OF A LOOP, SWITCH OR TRAP !!!
        # (the 'break' will bubble up the call stack and terminate the switch case in Test-Outer)
        break;
        write-host "inner after"
    }
}

Test-Outer
```

which gives this output:

```
entering outer
outer before
inner before
leaving outer
```

Note that we don't see `inner after` or `outer after` in the output - in short, the `break` inside the `Test-Inner` actually terminates the `switch` case inside `Test-Outer` and execution skips to the code *after* the `switch` block.

You're effectively controlling the flow of the *calling* code from within `Test-Inner`, which might work for your current script but it breaks the encapsulation of functions and as you can see from the documentation it's not recommended. A side effect is that trying to test `Test-Inner` with Pester results in `Test-Inner` unexpectedly terminating the calling Pester test harness...

A better approach might be for your `Test-Outer` function to decide whether to call `break` to control its own flow based on a result returned from `Test-Inner`:

```
function Test-Outer
{
    $x = 1
    write-host "entering outer"
    switch( $x )
    {
        1 {
            write-host "outer before"
            if( -not (Test-Inner $x) )
            {
                break;
            }
            write-host "outer after"
        }
    }
    write-host "leaving outer"
}


# returns $true for success or $false for failure
function Test-Inner
{
    param( $y )
    if( $y -eq 1 )
    {
        write-host "inner before"
        return $false
        write-host "inner after"
    }
    return $true
}

Test-Outer
```

We still see the same output from the second example...

```
entering outer
outer before
inner before
leaving outer
```

... but now the control flow (`break`) is local to the code where the control statements (`switch`) live and you can call `Test-Inner` without the `break` bubbling up to the caller which makes it safe to execute from other callers (e.g. Pester).

### Workaround

If you really can't live with moving the `break` out of `Test-Inner` you could wrap the call in a sacrificial control statement so *that* gets terminated rather than the main caller code.

For example, this version of `Test-Outer` *doesn't* exit the `switch` case when `Test-Inner` invokes `break` because it terminates the sacrificial `for` instead...

```
function Test-Outer
{
    $x = 1
    write-host "entering outer"
    switch( $x )
    {
        1 {
            write-host "outer before"
            # run *one* iteration, but also act as a sacrificial 
            # target for the effect of the "break" in Test-Inner
            for( $i = 0; $i -lt 1; $i++ ) { Test-Inner $x }
            write-host "outer after"
        }
    }
    write-host "leaving outer"
}
```

This now outputs the following:

```
entering outer
outer before
inner before
outer after
leaving outer
```

...but it means you'll have to add the workaround at every call-site - for example in your Pester tests it would become this:

```
It "Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1" {
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt 1; $i++ ) {
        Something-Function -SamplePath $($TestPath + $FileName)
    }
    Should -Invoke Write-Host -Exactly -Times 1
}
```

which will get messy very quickly, and overall it's probably better to invest time in cleaning up your script rather than making more convoluted tests to work around the funky `break` in the main script...

Comment: This explanation is really helpful, it does help me to understand the behavior of the `Break` statement that I never knew. Thanks lot.