# Break a foreach loop in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the path in Registry of a hardware device, which requires iterating over multiple Registry keys. I use `break` to exit the `foreach` loop after the first match is found, but for some reason, the `break` statement causes the outer `if` statement to exit without executing.

```
${device} = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "HID Keyboard%"');
if ( ${device} -ne ${null} ) {
    ${driver_key} = (${device}.GetDeviceProperties().DeviceProperties |
        Select-Object -Property data |
        Select-Object -Skip 6 -First 1).data;

    Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        foreach {
            if ( ${_}.GetValue("Driver") -eq "${driver_key}" ) {
                ${path} = ${_}.PSPath;
                Write-Output "Found!";
                break;
            }
        }

    Write-Output "${path}"; # this does not run
}
```

If I comment out the `break` statement, it will work. But that mean the `foreach` loop continues to iterate after a match is found. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, what does the percentage sign in `HID Keyboard%` means? I usually use `*` instead.

Comment: The `break` statement breaks you out of the `if` statement as well as the `foreach` loop. To get your desired output, you can use a `return` statement inside a `ForEach-Object` loop instead of a foreach loop. Something like: `ForEach-Object {if ( $_.GetValue("Driver") -eq "${driver_key}" ) {Write-Output "Found!" return $_.PSPath}}`

Comment: ```… | foreach { …. }``` is actually running ```| foreach-object { … }```, not the similarly named ```foreach( $x in $y) { … }```, and ```break``` inside a ```foreach-object``` terminates the next ```foreach```or ```switch``` up the call stack (or the entire script if none) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.4#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420522/3156906. If you want to ```break``` a loop use ```foreach( $x in $y ) { … }``` rather than ```foreach-object```.

Comment: See also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77743410/how-to-deal-with-break-statement-that-is-causing-issue-for-pester-on-should-inv - similar question with same underlying issue but slightly different scenario.