# Adding to an ArrayList within ForEach-Object reading a Word document

Tags: powershell

I am reading the Table of Contents of a Word document and trying to create an ArrayList that I can sort. Below is the Powershell script I have created. Nothing prints on the last line of the script as if the array list is empty. What am I doing wrong?

If I uncomment the $songsplit[1] and $songsplit[0] lines I can see that the information I'm pulling is what I expect (Artist and Song Name). And, if I take the [void] off the beginning of the line to Add to the array list, I can see it log the array numbers with the correct number of items.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

Clear-Host

# set input file
$filename = 'C:\Users\drschank\Desktop\Acoustic Solo Set - Copy.docx'

# create word object
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
# load word object as read-only
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($filename, $false, $true)
# create array to hold songs
$songArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

# loop through word paragraphs
$doc.Paragraphs | ForEach-Object {
    # when line found that separates active songs from inactive, exit for
    if($_.Range.Text -like "---*") {
        break
    }
    # if not table of contents line, split by song and artist
    if($_.Range.Text -notlike "Table of Contents*") {
        $fullsong = $_.Range.Text -split "`t"
        $songsplit = $fullsong[0] -split " – "

        # add to array
        [void]$songArrayList.Add($songsplit[1].ToString() + "`t" + $songsplit[0].ToString())  

        # $songsplit[1]
        # $songsplit[0]      
    }
}
$doc.close($false)
$songArrayList | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error without the word document, e. g. by setting `$songsplit = @('first', 'second')`?

Comment: Try: ``[void]$songArrayList.Add(($songsplit[1].ToString() + "`t" + $songsplit[0].ToString()))``. You can't put an expression directly in an method parameter. Either first assign it to a variable or use (an extra pair of) parentheses. See: [about parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

Comment: If I remove the foreach-object loop and just add to the arraylist, I have no problem. If I do literal values inside the loop, it still is empty after it exits. the loop. Something I just discovered is, if I put the "$songArrayList | Sort-Object" line just before the "break" statement it shows all of the values in the arraylist as I want them, and sorted. So, it appears to just be losing the contents of the arraylist after it exits the loop. I can probably work with that. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: ```break``` in a ```foreach-object``` doesn’t work like it does in a ```foreach``` - it bubble up to the next stack frame that supports ```break``` and exits *that*, which in your case is the entire runspace - it’s basically exiting your script. There was a similar question recently - I’ll see if I can find the link.

Comment: Here we go - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77743836/3156906 - slightly different context, but the same underlying problem - i.e. using ```break``` outside it’s intended constructs (```foreach```, etc) terminates a parent scope instead.

Comment: mclayton, thanks for the information and the link it was very helpful.